# Delay before Windows 10 startup app launches

Tags: windows-10, boot

I launch an [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script (.ahk) when Windows 10 boots, but it takes 10-20 seconds from when I'm logged in until the script starts. The strange thing is that the overall system is very snappy, so I can search and launch applications manually as soon as I'm logged in. Manually searching for and launching Chrome for instance, takes less than a second.

So the problem doesn't seem to be a hardware bottleneck; it looks like a software delay in Windows 10. Could it be that one of the other startup applications takes a long time to launch? "NVIDIA Backend" is one of the other two applications that launch on startup, could that be causing this strange delay? I used to run Windows 7 until a month back, and never once saw this issue.

**Edit:** *all* my startup applications are delayed for some seconds when I start Windows, which is frustrating as I always launch my different development tools via AutoHotkey. Is there any way to raise priority, or have them start earlier in the Windows boot. Does for instance `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` execute before the Startup folder? Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried switching things off at startup, temporarily, to see if that helps? Some things need to login online, like Microsoft OneDrive, and this can take some time. Perhaps these things are being prioritised over your AHK script.

Comment: It likely is your other programs that are configured to start, when the profile is accessed, that is causing the delay.  You ask if an application could be at fault, but you are the only one who can verify, if the other application is indeed the culprit.

Comment: maybe windows defender scans the script and casues the delay. try to temporarily disable the real time protection

Comment: Your suggestions may well be true. Is there any way to check what is causing the delay? Do applications at startup launch one after the other, or are they started "fire and release?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The startup delay can be modified in the registry as follows :

- Enter regedit
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Serialize`
- If `Serialize` does not exist, right-click on `Explorer`,
  choose New -> Key, and enter its name as `Serialize`
- Click on `Serialize`
- In the right-hand pane, right-click on empty space,
  choose New -> DWORD (32-bit) value,
  enter its name as `StartupDelayInMSec` and set it to 0.
- Reboot.

Other hints which might help :

- [Disable Fast Boot](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)
- Adjust Virtual Memory Settings
  Type `Performance` into the Start Menu and choose the `Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows`.
  Under the `Advanced` tab, you’ll see the size of the paging file (another name for virtual memory). Click `Change` to edit it.
  At the bottom of the screen you’ll see a Recommended amount of memory and a Currently Allocated amount.
  Ensure that current allocation is not way over the recommended number.
- Turn off Bash for Windows if you have installed it and don't need it.
- Update graphics drivers from the manufacturer's support website.

Comment: The serialize registry thing did the trick, it now starts in a couple of seconds.